# ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings - this method is obsolete error

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I am trying to set the row limit for my gridview webpart on sharepoint site in the appsettings of the web.config file.

```
<appSettings>
<add key ="RowLimit" value="6"/>
<add key="FeedCacheTime" value="300" />
<add key="FeedPageUrl" value="/_layouts/feed.aspx?" />
<add key="FeedXsl1" value="/Style Library/Xsl Style Sheets/Rss.xsl" />
<add key="ReportViewerMessages" value="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Analytics.UI.ReportViewerMessages, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
```

and then in my code file i am using the below statement

```
string x = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["RowLimit"];
```

this line is giving an error stating ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings "This method is obsolete",

What is that i am doing wrong? Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class instead.  `ConfigurationSettings` was deprecated in .NET 2.0. Use it the same way as you would use `ConfigurationSettings`, but be aware that you will have to add a reference to System.Configuration, if you don't have it already.

Answer (score 0):

The replacement is `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`.

Example:

```
using System.Configuration;
...
string x = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RowLimit"];
```